# I get a 401 error when accessing an MVC 2 app from the outside

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis, web-config

I have written an ASP.NET MVC 2 app that uses forms based authentication.  It is running on IIS 7.5.  When I access the site from the local box, I can see it.  When I access it from the outside, I get a generic 401 error.  It's odd.  Two other MVC2 sites that sit in the same virtual directory work fine no matter where you access it from.  I thought it might have been something to do with authorization, but the authorization tag between the three sites are near identical (except for the 'name' attribute).  Regardless, I commented out the authorization tag and got the same error (except now, it doesn't try to redirect me to the login page before getting the error).

I'm a bit lost as to what could be going on.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was including a page that required authorization in the master page.  So the Login page could not be rendered.